# Having trouble with flutter firebase messaging migration ]:

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> sendAndRetrieveMessage({String thatToken, String bodyMessage, String titleMessage}) async {
print('\n$thatToken' + '\n$bodyMessage' + '\n$bodyMessage');
await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
  sound: true,
  badge: true,
  alert: true,
  provisional: false,
);

await http.post(
  'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'key=$serverToken',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(
    <String, dynamic>{
      'notification': <String, dynamic>{'body': 'this is a body', 'title': 'this is a title'},
      'priority': 'high',
      'data': <String, dynamic>{'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK', 'id': '1', 'status': 'done'},
      'to': thatToken,
    },
  ),
);

final Completer<Map<String, dynamic>> completer = Completer<Map<String, dynamic>>();

FirebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    completer.complete(message);
  },
);

return completer.future;
```

}

Hello World! Code above is firebaseMessaging configuration code that I used before, and today, I'm finally trying migration to latest version, which is 8.0.0-dev.14 firebaseMessaging. And here I got tough issue to solve. Migration documentation says that '.configure()' is totally deleted and I have to use custom static methods for each cases. So, here comes the problem.

I could following substitution guides for other parts of migration from source code, but I cannot find out which exact code snippet is needed to perform same feature with code above. This is because I got only few ideas what those Completer or configuration are exactly doing. My fault.. ]:

So, I hope someone who have already got through these migration issues, especially the 'configure' method help me out. Lastly, code below is culprit with its error message. Thank you in advance [:

```
    FirebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    completer.complete(message);
  },
);
```

errorMessage for above snippet: error: The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging'.

Answer (score 2):

To migrate to Firebase messaging > 8.0.0 you can use `initializeApp` from Firebase core then add callbacks to the `onMessage` method of `FirebaseMessaging`

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

await Firebase.initializeApp();

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  completer.complete(message);
});
```

Source: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#plugin-changes